# Alternative to MTM and excel for tracking manual test plans

Tags: manual-testing, mtm, excel

We use to execute tens of manual tests plans sessions for identifying the build to be marked as release candidate and we mainly use Microsoft Test Manager and Excel. Both of them are fine but have some limitations so now I am looking for new tools for executing and tracking the results of manual test plans.
Main features of the tool (no one is mandatory):

- integrated with Visual Studio for quick bug tracking
- integrated with a source control like TFS or a repository as SharePoint for having an audit history
- powerful user interface for creating, managing and running test plans
- reporting features for sharing test results and trends
- open source or freeware would a plus but not necessary
- any other business

Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite test management  tool is Test Rail. This is a web based test management solution. I've found it to be easy to create and modify multiple test plans and tests. It also integrates with TFS and Visual Studio ( I don't have first hand experience with that however. We are a Atlassian/GIT shop). It is easy to generate test reports and custom test runs for your test passes with this tool which is another plus.

Another good feature is the API that they have. This can be a great resource when you make tests automated as you can have them update the test pass online.

They have a free trial so I would definitely check it out. It is a very versatile tool.

[Test Rail Website](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. I also hope to have further answers by testers with a direct experience with other tools for highlighting pro and cons of each.